# OOD - why car/bus/motocycle should derive from vehicle

Tags: oop, parking

Suppose we design a parking lot class. There are two ways to define the vehicles.

1)

```
Abstract class Vehicle {
        protected int size;
        private string plate;
        ...
}
class car : Vehicle{
     car(){base.size = enum.carSize;} 
 }
class bus: Vehicle{
     bus(){base.size = enum.busSize;} 
 }
```

2)

```
class Vehicle {
        private int size;
        protected string plate;
        public setSize(int size);
}
```

Then in parking lot class we can define

```
       Vehicle Car;
       vehicle Bus;
```

Which one is better? I see 1) is used in "cracking the coding interview". But I see 2) is better as it is simple. What should I use in interview?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need different kinds of functionalty for different kinds of Vehicle you dont need inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Vehicle` class has base methods and attributes, like `engine()`, `licensePlate = ''` and so on. All vehicles will have these methods and attributes.
Now `Car` and `Bus` class is different from each other, so you extend `Vehicle` class within `Car` and `Bus` classes to have same base functionality, but to be different in specific functionality (like `Car` can have `stereoType = ''` while `Bus` can have `hasSecondFloor = true`.

```
class Vehicle {
    private $licensePlate;
    public function startEngine()
    {
        /* ... */
    }

    public setLicensePlate()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public function _construct()
    {
       $this->setLicensePlate('ABC-123');
       $this->startEngine();
    }

    public function turnOnStereo()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```